# Storage Spaces Direct - New Volume on Virtual Disk

Tags: storage-spaces, windows-server-2016

Is it possible to add a new volume to an existing virtual disk?
The reason behind this is, that i would like to set certain values like interleave for the virtual disk. But right now you can either create a new virtual disk but can't add a volume to it or create a volume which creates a virtual disk with default settings.

Setup:
2 node cluster
storage spaces direct enabled
storagepool created

Comment: Are you building hyperconverged setup or SoFS?

Comment: Hyperconverged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

storage spaces direct operates lower than volume level, so you can't add a volume. Microsoft's most detailed how-to guide for now is here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/storage/storage-spaces/add-nodes?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Also, may I wonder what is the reason to set additional parameters? I'm learning s2d myself so would be glad to know if that provides any performance perks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
One of the reasons was that I like setting the interleave value to 64kb since I use HyperV workloads. But this is not possible with just the virtualdisk or volume command.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some testing I kind of figured it out. The key is to work with storage tiers. New-StorageTier has almost the same options as New-VirtualDisk. When you use the storage tier parameters from the New-Volume command, it creates a virtual disk using the storage tier values instead of default ones.